# How to create a SQL query WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a query as below:

```
declare 
@FromDate DATETIME = '2021-09-01 12:44:56.493',
@ToDate DATETIME = '2021-09-01 12:44:56.493',
@StartRow INT=1,
@EndRow INT=5;

WITH SWIFTMessages AS (
Select M.DocumentId, 
M.FileName, 
M.DateAdded, 
M.NotificationSent, 
M.DateNotificationSent,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY M.[DateAdded] ASC) AS RowNumber
from  [Swift].[MessageLog] AS M
Where ((@FromDate IS NULL OR @FromDate <= CAST(M.DateAdded AS DATE))
AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR @ToDate >= CAST(M.DateAdded AS DATE)))
), SWIFTMessageLogs AS (
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber DESC) AS RowNumberInverse
FROM SWIFTMessages
)

SELECT S.DocumentId, S.FileName, S.DateAdded, S.NotificationSent  -- getting error here
S.RowNumber + S.RowNumberInverse - 1 AS TotalRows
FROM SWIFTMessageLogs AS S
WHERE 
S.RowNumber >= @StartRow
AND S.RowNumber <= @EndRow
ORDER BY S.RowNumber

GO
```

But I am getting error like this

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

It cannot find anything under **S.**
Unfortunately I can't point out the issue in here. I would appreciate most if someone kindly point me out the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: a comma after notificationsent

Comment: If you were to format your columns line-by-line you would immediately spot the missing comma.

Comment: `COUNT(*) OVER ()` is more efficient at getting total rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe ?

```
SELECT
  S.DocumentId,
  S.FileName,
  S.DateAdded,
  S.NotificationSent, 
  (S.RowNumber + S.RowNumberInverse - 1) AS TotalRows
FROM SWIFTMessageLogs AS S
WHERE S.RowNumber >= @StartRow
AND S.RowNumber <= @EndRow
ORDER BY S.RowNumber
```